# Check if a number is a palindrome without changing it into string

Tags: python, iteration, palindrome

I'm having trouble with this problem that simply return True of False if a number `n`, is a palindrome.

Note: wherever I have a `____` indicates where there is a blank that needs to be filled in. There are 2 blank spaces.

```
def is_palindrome(n):
    x, y = n, 0
    f = lambda: ____
    while x > 0:
        x, y = ____ , f()
    return y == n
```

I've spent about an hour on this. I've found out that putting `x//10` in the second blank space will allow the function to iterate over the number of digits in `n`. It then comes down to the function `f`.

Ideally, every time it is called, it should add the last digit in `n` to a new number, `y`. Thus, if `n = 235`, the while loop will iterate 3 times, and each time `f()` is called, it should add `5`, `3`, and `2`, to the value `y`.

Comment: What do you mean "blanks that need to be filled in", just which parts of the second half of the string aren't palindromes of the first?

Comment: Lazy solution: `x = 0` and `f = lambda: n if str(n)==str(n)[::-1] else n+1`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's the logic: `(y * 10) + x % 10`

```
def is_palindrome(n):
    x, y = n, 0
    f = lambda: (y * 10) + x % 10
    while x > 0:
        x, y = x//10 , f()
    return y == n

print(is_palindrome(123454321))
# True
print(is_palindrome(12))
# False
```

`y*10` moves the current y to the left by 1 digit, and `x%10` adds the last digit.

```
print(is_palindrome(235))
# False
```

Pre-iteration: `x = 235`, `y = 0`

First iteration: `x = 23`, `y = 5`

Second iteration: `x = 2`, `y = 53`

Third iteration: `x = 0`, `y = 532`

Comment: Here is a [flowchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96f0t.png) produced by [Abbasov Alexander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2304719/abbasov-alexander), which can be added to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Excellent solution, mate! Maybe one little suggestion. Your solution iterates over all n digits, but you have only to iterate n/2 digits. Moreover, you can handle negative values directly because they aren't palindromes.

```
def is_palindrome(x):
    if x < 0 or (x % 10 == 0 and x != 0):
        return False
    head, tail = x, 0
    while head > tail:
        head, tail = head // 10, tail * 10 + head % 10
    # When the length is an odd number, we can get rid of the middle digit by tail // 10
    return head == tail or head == tail // 10
```

Time complexity: *O(log(n))* because we divided 10 in every iteration
Space complexity: *O(1)*

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code which has 11510 leetcode test cases and it is accepted
check a number is palindrome without converting it into string

```
var isPalindrome = function(x) {
let list=[]
if(x<0){
    return false
}
while(x>0){
    if(x<10){
        list.push(parseInt(x))
        break;
    }
    let num=parseInt( x%10)
    list.push(num)
    x=parseInt( x/10)
}  
for(var i=0;i<list.length/2;i++){
    if(list[i]!=list[list.length-(i+1)]){
        return false
    }
}
return true
```

};

thanks,