# Why does my code output 'true' when ran on LeetCode but 'false' when ran on my own? (python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Not sure what to do here, anyone know what's up? I'm trying to find if a number is a palindrome, and I'm getting hung up with the input `-121`. The output should be `'false'`, as in it is not a palindrome, whereas `121` is.

LeetCode code:

```
class Solution:
    def isPalindrome(self, x: int) -> bool:
        x = str(x)
        xrev = x[::-1]
        if x == xrev:
            return 'true'
        else:
            return 'false'
```

This returns 'true', 'false' is expected. Whereas my code ran on Atom returns 'false' as expected:

```
def isPalindrome(x):
    x = str(x)
    xrev = x[::-1]
    if x == xrev:
        return 'true'
    else:
        return 'false'

print(isPalindrome(-121))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Why are you returning strings that happen to have the words `"true"` and `"false"` in them instead of boolean values `True` and `False`? LC is probably treating `"false"` as truthy. Try running this code in your repl: `bool("false")`. It's best to avoid bare booleans anyway, you can just `return str(x) == str(x)[::-1]`.

Comment: Since your method has type hint `-> bool` it definitely should not be returning strings.

Comment: There is no case where a negative number is a palindrome, so you should really start with `if x < 0` check, or read the conditions of your LeetCode site that probably say the input is always `x > 0`

Comment: @OneCricketeer Why make it more complicated?

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode The "correct" (i.e. optimal) way to do this is to **not** use a string and instead modulo and divide by 10's to get the individual integers to compare

Comment: @OneCricketeer In what way is that "optimal"? Sounds like more code and slower.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode It doesn't require creating two string objects. It still runs in linear time. More code doesn't mean anything is slower

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode it's definitely more code, and the shorter code is both easier to write and verify for correctness.  But I think the speed will be a wash, integer to string conversion has to follow roughly the same process as digit extraction.

Comment: @OneCricketeer Well it requires creating int objects instead. Linear time sounds wrong, either you consider the input numbers limited and then it's constant time, or you don't and then it's probably quadratic time. I didn't mean it's slower *because* it's more code.

Comment: @OneCricketeer What do you do with the "individual integers"? Modulo 10 only gives you the *last* digit, how do you compare it with the *first* digit? Do you store them all in a list and compare at the end, or how do you do it?

Comment: @MarkRansom [Small benchmark](https://tio.run/##fZDdTsMwDIXv@xS@64/Ktmywn0jlirdACHVrSg2tUyWeJjTt2UvStEiARG6S40/HPk7/yY2mzb43w1Ab3QFjp5ABu14bnlQ0ElNS5a6JnBqNJ2UDqtQJu7Kd2VOQUVSpGvqyRVaWXy2bhFIZgTsWCgh6lEbx2ZCvuvKzlHfi5ZcZib/NlwZbBRSEPwTLZQFiNRaiWhtQgOQDv6lErHIQ@8lKbu4asgzUKNFJ3zmOF@8aKZmWSmKx3tw/bHf7Q5zDR0FpGnKyzx3@JGnL7liV8ud@mOZA5@6oTCEmC/5j8bP/Wnrj63XsGkq4@rebm4FQ21Tu8urmgxPPCGd0CKh49BTQwpVxyVYuRH0bE1iwrb4oE6fD8AU) where just dividing by 10 until 0 is already 15 times slower than the whole string solution.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode interesting benchmark.  I suppose `str` is faster because it's done in C instead of pure Python, and it's a Knuth algorithm which you would expect to be more optimized than the naive division.

Comment: @MarkRansom [New benchmark](https://tio.run/##fVDLTsMwELznK/aWhwKtW2jTSLnxFwhFaeyQhWQd2S4IIb492HUSUIvYiz07O/uY4cO0krbZoMaxUbIHg71AA9gPUpkJBWdGVcTtMzF1K7EW2lNc1NhX3cw9eBgEXDQwVB0aoU2pjYowzgOwoaEAj89QCXNS5LI2/ZjnN@zpQoxkFvF7i50A9MAFwmpVAFt7DZXaDu9Kjm@oUZKOaBI2UkEJSO6UZ7GkXdDSwhWJnyK2ToFlUyXZtTeQJCACP7cAt1gY3r5IpGjyJArZZnt3v9tnhzCF14Li2J9p3Nne0qir@iOv8kt7UqBTfxSqYJME/5F4U64k/FrylyeXukG5fk1oF8nh0/3tvgkwsYvzfcq/3MFkZgpn6uAp21nPHP/NhfE4fgM): `n_small_divisions` does as many divisions (but of smaller numbers) as `palitest_int` but is much faster. So it's not the Python, it's the division work in C.

Comment: @MarkRansom And actually we could also tell that just by looking at the times. They grow quadratically (doubling the number of digits quadrupled the time). The Python code interpretation is only linear (twice as many digits => twice as many divisions), and thus not responsible for that quadratic growth.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode yes, working with really large integers is really slow in Python - that's not a surprise.  Your benchmark is using some outrageously large integers.  I once took advantage of that slowness to create a function that's faster than `str` when used with integers above about 100,000 digits: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53644080/5987

Comment: @MarkRansom Very elegant. I'm not surprised that mul/div on two large numbers leads to something faster. I was hoping for a similar speedup for `str` on large numbers. [Back here](https://tio.run/##fVBdS8QwEHzvr9i3fnBag@idgfrkvxCRXpvahSYpyR6HlP72mm1aQUH3ZTMzzO5sxk/qrbk/jW5ZOmc1EGqFBKhH62hDyaq42rShbUrTW2yUj1KrGtT1sGsvESZJqzoY6wFJeXr35DKTywRCeagg4hU6RRdnmA30q5Q34u2XGQ19m689DgpMBFwGyrICcbcSSWddYNBw4A@ViQOI0@bEsJYnpccUCtiWm4s@Kwc8oCgeVoo4X7w9G2p9bmv58w7MD5uvii2OIvzHx4v/8I2OxS4NoyVM/A4JChDqMZfHQztzdEO7hLv0FKXqmVVADxNhSV7eim5eY3jwg72G4/hPJqzmNF@WLw), divisions-by-10 seems faster than the str ...

Comment: @MarkRansom ... solution for numbers with <= 6 digits, but then again that's still just the divisions, as I don't know how OneCricketeer intends to do the comparing.

Comment: @don't See here how you get the digits https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50660606/check-if-a-number-is-a-palindrome-without-changing-it-into-string

Comment: @OneCricketeer [Benchmark](https://pastebin.com/raw/PDDBNbWH) - That first solution is slower for any number size, up to 40 times slower. That second solution is a bit faster for numbers < 100 but then becomes up to 25 times slower. Do you still consider them optimal?

Answer (score 2):

As @khelwood in the comments pointed out, since the LeetCode code is hinted to return a boolean, the string value is automatically converted to a boolean value, which only if the string is empty, will return False.

Corrected code:

```
class Solution:
    def isPalindrome(self, x: int) -> bool:
        x = str(x)
        xrev = x[::-1]
        if x == xrev:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! I thought I should have used 'true' and 'false' because of the requested outputs by LC.

Comment: @Sam this can be simplified even further.  When you see `if condition: return True else: return False` you can always replace it with `return condition`.  Or worst case, `return bool(condition)`.

Answer (score 0):

try this, instead of true and false return 1 and 0:

```
class Solution:
    def isPalindrome(self, x) -> bool:
        x = str(x)
        xrev = x[::-1]
        if x == xrev:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
```

Comment: Did you know that True==1 and False==0 by definition?  While your code might work, it's better to be explicit.