# Error during output in Design Parking system question

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am solving [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/design-parking-system/) question on LeetCode. I have the following code:

```py
class ParkingSystem:

    def __init__(self, big: int, medium: int, small: int):
        self.big=big
        self.medium =medium
        self.small =small

    def addCar(self, carType: int) -> bool:
        if carType == 1 and self.big>0:
            self.big -=1
            return 'true'
        elif carType ==2 and self.medium>0:
            self.medium -=1
            return 'true'
        elif carType ==3 and self.small>0:
            self.small -=1
            return 'true'
        else:
            return 'false'
```

I am unable to understand, why I am getting the wrong output?
Input

```
["ParkingSystem", "addCar", "addCar", "addCar", "addCar"]
[[1, 1, 0], [1], [2], [3], [1]]
```

Output

```
[null, true, true, false, false]
```

*my output*: Output

```
[null,true,true,true,true]
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't reproduce your output. I get: `[<null>, 'true', 'true', 'false', 'false']`. btw I would expect that you should be returning either: `True`, or `False`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68946065/why-does-my-code-output-true-when-ran-on-leetcode-but-false-when-ran-on-my-o/68946151#68946151

Answer (score 1):

Your function will return a boolean value because you have put a boolean pointer at the function definition.

Change this:

```
def addCar(self, carType: int) -> bool:
```

To this:

```
def addCar(self, carType: int) -> str:
```

Of course, you can also change the return string to actual booleans too.

Comment: I think that the return type definition: `-> bool:` is proscribed by `leetcode`.

Comment: I don't think so, I've seen another question pretty similar to this.

Comment: I meant that I followed the link to the `leetcode` website and I can see the return type there.

Answer (score 1):

```
class ParkingSystem:

    def __init__(self, big: int, medium: int, small: int):
        self.big=big
        self.medium =medium
        self.small =small

    def addCar(self, carType: int) -> bool:
        if carType == 1 and self.big>0:
            self.big -=1
            return True
        elif carType ==2 and self.medium>0:
            self.medium -=1
            return True
        elif carType ==3 and self.small>0:
            self.small -=1
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Return the boolean value either True or False.